# Opening large son file at app launch forcing long start time

Tags: ios, json, xcode

I am creating a game which is made up of different game boards which are stored as dictionaries, in an array, in a json file. The json file is quite large, over 3,000 objects in the array, about 23mb in size. The way that I am loading this file at the moment is in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions in the appDelegate implementation file like so:

```
NSString * filePath =[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"words" ofType:@"json"];

NSError * error;
NSString* fileContents =[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];


if(error)
{
    NSLog(@"Error reading file: %@",error.localizedDescription);
}


NSDictionary *data = (NSDictionary *)[NSJSONSerialization
                                      JSONObjectWithData:[fileContents dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                      options:0 error:NULL];

wordsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[data objectForKey:@"results"]];
```

Then I can retrieve the array from anywhere in the app by calling:

```
NSArray *wordsArray = appDelegate.wordsArray;
```

It works great except for the fact that the app takes over 15 seconds to load on an iPhone 4 device which is way too long and I understand that an app can get rejected for loading times this long.

Can someone suggest a better way to go about this,

thanks

Comment: Use intermediate screen which looks like splash or loading screen and do the work there. You should avoid `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` for any major task

Comment: You should do long tasks in a background thread, using GCD or NSOperation in order to not block the UI thread. Google "iOS import large dataset". Also take a look at Core Data to avoid importing your data at each application startup.

Comment: Put the individual game boards in separate files. Also JSON is really not good storage format, it is really a transport format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by Yedidya, you may want to show some interesting stuff to keep the user engaged.

On top of that, the most important thing is to:

- keep your UI responsive
- do the loading of file / network resource on background thread. There are ample code samples showing the same. Use one of `performselectorOnBackground` or `dispatch_async(some_global_queue)` to perform background task.
- Once done, come back to main screen / Game UI using `performselectorOnMainThread` or `dispatch_asynch(dispatch_get_main_queue)`.

Here is the gist:

```
    //START BUSY CURSOR HERE
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), 
    ^{
        // Read JSON file here
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), 
      ^{
        //STOP BUSY CURSOR 
       //PERFORM UI UPDATE HERE
    });
```

Comment: Great, I was trying to load the file outside of appDelegate but the ui would freeze up, hence why I took the easy option if adding it to the delegate in the first place, I'll give this a go now

Comment: the apple recommended way is not to do any heavy stuff inside didfinishlaunching. You just need to spawn things off to global queue and then load your UI over main queue with data. Meanwhile, there is no problem showing empty view controller - with your preferred busy cursor or animation. You may start all that in "START BUSY CURSOR" area.

Answer (score 3):

Use something like core data. It is designed for storing information like this.

Also, DONT PUT IT IN THE APP DELEGATE! The app delegate is there to respond to app events. It is not a dump for all the data that your app needs.

Answer (score 2):

Set an enter screen with loader (Do an interesting loader for the users...) and load the data at this screen. When it finished, launch your game...

Comment: Would the fact that the app is still loading for 15 + seconds still hurt my chances of getting approval?

Comment: Hi, the app will reject or crash if the app doesn't load in a short enough time. - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1592/_index.html
. If you will load the data at s new screen, it should not be a problem.
Even though, If you will just present static screen while a long loading, apple may reject it because of UX problems...

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by Yedidya, you may want to show some interesting stuff to keep the user engaged.

On top of that, the most important thing is to:

- keep your UI responsive
- do the loading of file / network resource on background thread. There are ample code samples showing the same. Use one of `performselectorOnBackground` or `dispatch_async(some_global_queue)` to perform background task.
- Once done, come back to main screen / Game UI using `performselectorOnMainThread` or `dispatch_asynch(dispatch_get_main_queue)`.

Answer (score 1):

Apple has many guides to help you:

- [Tuning for Performance and Responsiveness](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/MOSXAppProgrammingGuide/Performance/Performance.html) for Mac but should be applicable to iOS.
- [Performance Overview Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/PerformanceOverview/Introduction/Introduction.html)
- [Launch Time Performance Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/LaunchTime/LaunchTime.html) is deprecated, but may still have some useful tips.

Generally, performance is a product of App design, so in order to improve performance you may have to redesign large parts of your app.

I would follow these steps:

1. Measure CPU usage and disk-access in [Instruments user Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html).
2. Not load and parse such a large file on the main thread.
3. Split the file as much as possible.
4. Pre-load resources if nothing is happening in the app.